# How to retrieve data from two tables?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have two tables

```
posts 
------
post_id | user_id | post_title | post_content
```

And

```
users
--------
id | user_name | user_ . .. . . . and so on
```

I need to fetch all posts with the user data 
to show the post writer etc..

How can I achieve this using CakePHP queries?

Comment: define relationship in `model` and use `$this->Post->find('all');` that will give you result you want.

Comment: yeah !! I just asked for the relationship in the Model

Comment: Please try to use the CakePHP conventions and don't prefix your field names; e.g. Rename `user_name` to just `name`. CakePhp will already use the Model-alias as a prefix (e.g. `User.name`) to prevent duplicated field names. Read about the conventions here: [`Model and Database conventions`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions). **Not using conventions** (especially for (primary) key fields) may require you to specify Primary and Foreign key fields in all your models and relations and make things a lot more difficult

Answer (score 3):

In your UserModel you define:

```
var $hasMany = 'Post';
```

In your PostModel you define:

```
var $belongsTo = 'User';
```

Then you can get all post of some user doing:

```
$this->User->findAllById($id, array('recursive' => 2));
```

Or you can get ALL posts associated with the respective users doing:

```
$this->Post->find("all", array('recursive' => 2));
```

**EDIT:**
Your Posts id column is named post_id so you must define primary key in your PostModel since CakePHP conventions is that primary key should be named id:

```
public $primaryKey = 'post_id';
```

Comment: but how to link the foreign_key in the models post.user_id with user.id

Comment: @Alsemany you only need to link if your database was not structured according to CakePHP conventions. CakePHP expects that **table Posts has a foreign key column named user_id** and it seems that you have. At least the name is right but make sure that you defined user_id as a foreign key. Oh, I see that your Posts id column is post_id. Maybe that is the problem. Check my answer again.

Comment: hi :( 
this is the right way to do the lnk to the foreign key 
public $belongsTo = array('User' => array('className' => 'User', 'foreignKey' => 'user_id' ));
this is in the Post Model 
thanks any way

Comment: @Alsemany did you tried to define primary key instead `public $primaryKey = 'post_id';`? Your foreign key name follows CakePHP conventions so I guess you don't need to define it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->Post->find('all',array('fields'=>array('User.*'),'conditions'=>array('Post.user_id=User.id')),
        joins' => array(
            array(
                'alias' => 'User',
                'table' => 'users',
                'type' => 'Inner',
                'conditions' => array('User.user_id' =>$id)
            )
        )
 ));
```